# Texture Paint behaviour in regard to a Texture

Tags: texture-painting

If I have texture paint working, and add a new Texture then it stops working. Or it behaves weird.
It's a bit tough to explain in textual format for me so I made a video about it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltLqniomK6U

To explain in short, when I add a texture here, then texture paint stops working or behaves weird:

[image]

Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: Blender requires the target texture be known.  This can be indicated with the Texture  Paint sidebar . I suggest you see tutorials on this topic.  It will save you time. Your previous question is very similar to this.  If you are reporting what you believe to be  defect .. please state so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes atomicbezierslinger is correct, you can do this by pressing the
Browse material to be linked button, then from the drop down menu, select your UV image you unwrapped from your object.
[image]

*Similar to how you assign textures from a texture node in the Shader editor.*

Comment: If the mapping is incorrect, UV unwrap the object again and repeat.